# Is there an R function for finding most frequency items (LHS) in the rules of a given RHS?

Tags: apriori

I would like to identifiy the most frequent items (LHS) in the rules of a given consequence (RHS).
From the command below I get the LHS frequency, and I would like to add the RHS info to the same output.

rowSums(as(lhs(r), "ngCMatrix"))

## Get the rules:

rules <- apriori(d, parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.05, conf=0.1), appearance = list(default="lhs", rhs=c("Causa=CA", "Causa=CB", "Causa=CE", "Causa=OT", "Causa=AB", "Causa=AT")))

Any suggests?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at function `itemFrequency`. I am not sure what you mean with "add the  RHS info." Please post a complete, runnable example and the output that you would like.

Comment: I would like to get both functions `rowSums(as(lhs(r), "ngCMatrix"))` and`rowSums(as(lhs(r), "ngCMatrix"))` on a single output. I would like to have this output:                                                                                                
A => X        A => Y      A => W                                                   
449            430           681

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you need. Do I understand right that you want the most frequent LHS items in all the rules with the same RHS? If so then mine only rules with a single RHS at a time and use `itemFrequency` on the LHS to find the most frequent items.